# Nodejs module to find files?

Tags: file, node.js, module, finder

I search a module to find files in nodejs.

I would like something like:

```
var finder = require('finder');
var path = finder.find('/path/to/*.js');
```

Then path is an array with for example:

```
/path/to/file.js
/path/to/sub/file.js
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In addition to @pksunkara answer:

- https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob

Answer (score 2):

- https://github.com/zzak/gsub
- https://github.com/dvv/meta-fs

Answer (score 1):

For simple searches supporting callbacks you can use:
https://github.com/yuanchuan/find

Alternatively, you can use `filehound` which supports async (callbacks, promises) and sync calls. In addition, you can specify multiple search criteria like file extension, size etc

Example:

```
const Filehound = require('filehound');

const files = Filehound.create()
   .ext('js')
   .findSync();

console.log(files) // json files
```

Repo:
https://github.com/nspragg/filehound

API docs:
https://nspragg.github.io/filehound/

Answer (score 0):

[fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack) can do this in a very simple way:

```js
const jetpack = require("fs-jetpack");

// sync way
const files = jetpack.find("my_folder", { matching: "*.js" });
console.log(files);

// or async way
jetpack.findAsync("my_folder", { matching: "*.js" }).then(files => {
  console.log(files);
});
```